# Optimizing workflow to update internally owned cocoapods dependencies?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

Let's say I have a main `Project A` with several **cocoapods dependencies** (which are internally owned by our organization's cocoapods repo).

Let's say I'm working on `Project A`, and while working on it I find a fix on a `DependencyB`, so I modify the code in that dependency while still being on ProjectA's Xcode project.

What would be the best **workflow** to push the changes on that dependency to it's own repository and then updating that dependency in `Project A`?

I would really like some ways so **avoid**, **completely automate** or **simplify** the following workflow (which is a PITA)

## Worflow to avoid

1. `git clone git@github.com:Organization/DependencyB.git`
2. Make your changes in the dependency project (the **same changes** that where made while fixing the issue that I found while working on `Project A`)
3. Update the `DependencyB.podspec` file

   ```
   s.version = "0.1.7"
   s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/Organization/DependencyB.git", :tag => "0.1.7" }
   ```
4. Commit & Tag this dependency's version

   ```
   git add -A
   git commit -m 'Made some changes'
   git tag -a 0.1.7 -m 'This is an awesome tag :D'
   git push origin master
   git push --tags origin
   ```
5. Update the organiazation's private cocoapods repo (which I stored in `~/`)

   ```
   cd ~/.cocoapods/OrganizationPrivateRepo/CoverFlux
   mkdir 0.1.7
   cd 0.1.7
   ```
6. copy the updated DependencyB.podspec to the organiation's private repo (cloned in `~/.cocoapods`)

   ```
   ~/.cocoapods/OrganizationPrivateRepo/DependencyB/0.1.7/CoverFlux.podspec
   ```
7. Commit changes in the private repository & push to remote

   ```
   cd ~/.cocoapods/OrganizationPrivateRepo/
   git commit -am 'Added version 0.1.7 to DependencyB spec'
   git push origin master
   ```
8. Finally proceed to the initial's 'Project A' folder and update

   ```
   pod update
   ```

**Note:**

Project's A podfile looks like:

```
    platform :ios, '6.0'
    pod 'DependencyB'
```

Comment: I wonder how you're able to work on DependencyB while staying in Project A. Any tutorials/blogs on how to do this? After pod install everything seems very static to me, can I develop on a pod after pod install from the project using it? :O

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tips to simplify your workflow. Beyond these, you might need to consider making some additional scripts.

First, I recommend that you keep your podspec file located at the root of your project. So, DependencyB.git would have the file DependencyB.podspec.

**Simplify Step 3**

Change your source tag to reference the version. This way, you only need to change the version line in your podspec.

```
s.source = { :git => "https://github.com/Organization/DependencyB.git", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
```

**Simplify Steps 5, 6, and 7**

Run the following from your DependencyB.git directory. (Assuming you have your podspec there as I suggested above)

```
pod push OrganizationPrivateRepo DependencyB.podspec
```

If DependencyB.podspec is the only podspec file, you don't even need to include it on the line, yielding:

```
pod push OrganizationPrivateRepo
```

**Step 4**

Finally, I think that simplifying Step 4 is possible, but is one of those things that varies between organizations and individual developers as it is part of their workflow. For example, I normally commit from my IDE.

Such scripts could be integrated into the podspec so that they update the `s.version` value. Or alternatively, get the correct tag from the `s.version` value.

**UPDATE: Simplify Step 2**

It looks like you are making a change twice to DependencyB. You can have CocoaPods setup a symbolic link. In ProjectA's Podfile, set the following:

```
pod 'DependencyB', :path => "../path/to/DependencyB'
```

You can now edit the files in DependencyB from ProjectA. You will need to run `pod update` after making this change. After that, the changes to the source will be available immediately since it is a symbolic link. I have had trouble making Git commits from Xcode when doing this, but other than that it works well.

Comment: You're right about step 4, thanks for the tips, will see if someone else comes up with more ideas, this sounds fair though :)